# Monitoring javafx task for completion

Tags: java, javafx

How do you check whether a javafx background task is done without interrupting progressIndicator associated with the task progress.

```
try
{
AddMeteorParents amp = new AddMeteorParents(textOpenDB.getText(), textMeteorData.getText(), DatabaseTools.meteorVersion.Meteor14);
proIndAddData.setVisible(true);
proIndAddData.progressProperty().bind(amp.progressProperty());
Thread th = new Thread(amp);
th.setDaemon(true);
th.start();
}
```

The class AddMeteorParents extends from Task. ProIndAddData is a javafx progress Indicator. If I add th.join() or th.isAlive() the javafx progressIndicator stops working? I would like to display a message when the task is done.

Comment: I need to run a second background task when task 1 is done. I have no way of doing it without interrupting progressIndicator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to run one back ground task after another (without any interruption to progressIndicators) using ExecutorService.

```
ExecutorService eservice = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1);
```

Comment: I created some [sample code](https://gist.github.com/jewelsea/4947946) which illustrates this approach.

Answer (score 0):

The javadoc of [javafx.concurrent.Task](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/concurrent/Task.html) says:

> Reacting To State Changes Generically
>
> Sometimes you may want to write a Task which updates its progress,
>   message, text, or in some other way reacts whenever a state change
>   happens on the Task. For example, you may want to change the status
>   message on the Task on Failure, Success, Running, or Cancelled state
>   changes.

http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/concurrent/Task.html#onSucceededProperty

Answer (score 0):

use `javafx.concurrent.Task` to wrap your task code,the `stateProperty` is what you need check.

see my gist https://gist.github.com/John-Chan/ee6b783c6e96c09c79a03a3da8fe14c4